# Rhythmbox can't extract from CD: Internal data stream error

Tags: 22.04, rhythmbox

Ubuntu 22.04.1
Rhythmbox 3.4.6

When I try to rip/extract a CD I get "Error transferring track - Internal data stream error"

I've tried installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad and gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

I also tried removing and reinstalling rhythmbox itself.

What else can I try?

Comment: Try installing even more plugins https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1672035/comments/6

Comment: ,,, or it can be due to some copy protection feature.